# How can I make this animation smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, transform

I have a small plnkr that I'm using to play with AngularJS and ngAnimate. I'm now learning about css3 transitions and transform. The collapse/expand animation looks cool, but the element takes up all the space that it will eventually occupy before the animation completes. It's even worse on collapse because the text shrinks and disappears but then the container snaps closed instead of elegantly closing.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hzJlOstUCeH2sB47OstS?p=preview

I've been trying to simulate JQuery's slideDown animation but unless I know the height I'm animating to, I can't seem to get this animation to be smooth. Does anyone know how JQuery's slideDown function is able to smoothly animate variable height elements?

[image]

Comment: did you update the plunker -- it is different from the .gif version.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Yes I did. Once I had a solution I continued updating my demo. The demo works as it should now. Thanks for reading my question though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to make the collapse/expand animation look smooth by changing `line-height`. This allow me to animate the lines without knowing the total height. Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/h0vv3WzMtMrIOYfwhuDS?p=preview). This might not be what you want it to look like, but it is smoother than before. I suspect JQuery's slideDown does something with the computed height, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a tiny bit jerky as it does it but I think it is better than before. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the browser is having performance issues animating this. I ran a Chrome time line and it dips below 30 fps at occasions, and its not due to repaint. IE on the other hand runs it buttery smooth. There is probably a better way, but probably more complicated.

Comment: Also, you should be using -webkit-transform, since scale() is only available in -web-kit-transform for Chrome

Comment: That's weird. I'm using Chrome and scale without the vendor prefix appears to be working o_O

Comment: It looks different if you use the prefix. I updated the Plunker, you should check it, also if you just remove the transforms, it will look exactly the same.

Comment: I actually use the transforms to do some more complicated animations. I just changed it to a simple `scaleY` for this question :). I will check out your update. Edit: I'm not seeing any change by using the vendor prefix. It's still a bit jaggy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The jankiness is a minor concern. Overall I'd say [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/hzJlOstUCeH2sB47OstS?p=preview) looks pretty sweet now!

Comment: Nice fly in effect in Firefox and IE :)